# How to return Json data in django

Tags: python, django, email, frameworks

Instead of rendering the html page, I want to return Json data from the following blocks of code but I don't know how to implement it. I don't want to use the rest_framework. When I use `render` the page renders but when I use `JsonResponse`it throws back an error.

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.core.mail import send_mail 

def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        title = request.POST.get("title")
        message = request.POST.get("message")

        data = {
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
            "title": title,
            "message": message
        }
        message =  '''    
        New message: {}

        From: {}
        '''.format(data["message"], data['email'])
        send_mail(data["title"], message, '', ['mine@gmail.com'])
  
    return JsonResponse(request, 'contact_us/contact_us.html', safe=False)
```

```
contact.html

<form action="" method="POST" class="contact_us">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <div>Name</div>
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Email</div>
        <input type="text" name="email">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Title</div>
        <input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Message</div>
        <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows='10'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit", value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello @C-Bizz you should provide error in question

Comment: You can't pass template in `JsonResponse`  if you want to pass some code of  `HTML` you can do something like this  `mytags = <h1>Hello</h1>` and than you have to pass it like this in your `JsonResponse` `return JsonResponse({'mymessage':mytags})`

Comment: Thanks @Ankit Tiwari for the explanation. In this case, the form to fill so as to send the email is in the template. How do I work arround this? Am I supposed to to copy the code for the form in the template and paste it in `views.py` in order for JsonResponse to work? If yes, is it a good practice? Sorry for asking many questions, I want to know how to work arround situations like this without using rest framework. I want to use a react application to fetch the Json data that will be returned.

Comment: you want to send email to user after form submission?

Comment: you can do something like this in your view `def send_mail(request):` `get_all_data_from_frontend` and than send email to user after email is send to user you have to return success message as `JsonResponse`

Comment: Let me know what actually you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `React` than you have to get data from frontend you don't need to send a template you have to create a contact page in `React` which contain your contact form

than you have to access all data in your view

```
def send_mail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            name = request.POST.get("name")
            email = request.POST.get("email")
            title = request.POST.get("title")
            message = request.POST.get("message")
    
            data = {
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "title": title,
                "message": message
            }
           current_site = get_current_site(request)
           mail_subject = 'My Subject.'
           message = get_template('contact_us/contact_us.html').render(data)
           to_email = request.POST.get('email')
           email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
           email.content_subtype = "html"
           email.send()
     return JsonResponse({"Success":'Check your email.'})
```

you have to import this two things from `django.template.loader import get_template` `from django.core.mail import EmailMessage`

**NOTE : ** use `try: except:` if you want except the exceptions and use `email.send(fail_silently=False)` to avoid email error such as failed to send mail
etc.

check official doc. for more information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects

Comment: Thank so much @ Ankit Tiwari. When I test the code on Postman using post request I get an error:  `current_site = get_current_site(request)
NameError: name 'get_current_site' is not defined`

Comment: Hello @C-Bizz you don't need to add your current site in email the code i provided you it was used in my activate account logic i passes my current domain with token and user id but in your case you don;t need this so you can remove it

Comment: if you still want to use it for any purpose you can import it `from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site` than it will work